# Как отключить бенихоп в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Занимаюсь созданием простой FPS игры, нашел хороший гайд по контроллеру персонажа, но в отдав проект на тесты, обнаружилось, что в игре присутствует бенихоп, вот собственно код, отвечающий за передвижение, есть ли какие-то возможности избавится от бенихопа?

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public CharacterController controller;
    public float speed = 10f;
    public float gravity = -9.81f;
    public float jumpHeihgt = 2f;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public LayerMask lavaMask;
    public Transform lavaCheck;

    Vector3 velocity;
    bool isGrounded;
    bool isDead;

    void Update()
    {
        isDead = Physics.CheckSphere(lavaCheck.position, groundDistance, lavaMask);

        if (isDead)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
        }

        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

        if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeihgt * -2f * gravity);
        }

        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 moving = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

        controller.Move(moving * speed * Time.deltaTime);


        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);

        
    }
} ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Way 1

Сделай замер Velocity твоего персонажа при прямом беге по поверхности

А потом в `Update` огранчь эту скорость у персонажа и сделай так что бы скорость в плоскости XZ не превышала эту скорость. То есть если скорость выше - сохраняй тот же вектор(направление), но убавляй скорость к этой максимальной.

---

Way 2

Как еще один вариант - можешь ограничить передвижение во время прыжка. То есть если у персонажа есть задан вектор скорости во время начала прыжка - то все, дальше если `Grounded == false` - то управлять персонажем нельзя. Это создаст еще дополнительные ограничения и не даст возможность менять направление персонажа в воздухе. А, значит, и не даст бенихопить.

Comment: помогло ограничить скорость, теперь максимально невыгодно прыгать бочком, спасибо большое!